# Merge eloquent collection with query in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to merge an eloquent collection with a query builder?

In this example, I've got 3 tables. An images table, a tag table, and an images_tag table. I also have eloquent relationships in both the Images and Tag models.

**Tag.php:**

```
class Tag extends Model {

 protected $table = 'tags';

 public $timestamps = false;

 protected $fillable = [
    'tagname',
 ];

 public function Images() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('CommendMe\Models\Images');
 }  

}
```

**Images.php:**

```
public function tags() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('CommendMe\Models\Tag');
}
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
$tag = Tag::where('tagname', $query)->first();

$imagesWithTag = $tag->images;

$imagesWithoutTag = Images::where('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%");

$images = $imagesWithTag + $imagesWithoutTag
   ->whereIn('mature', [0, $mature])
   ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours($withinHours))
   ->orderBy($orderByString, 'desc')
   ->Paginate(50);
```

Essentially just taking the query (which returns an array from the images table), and the collection (which also returns an array from the images table), combine and sort the results.

Is this possible?

**EDIT 2:**

When trying Paras's new answer, the following error occurs:

> FatalThrowableError in SearchController.php line 98: Call to a member
>   function toArray() on integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$tag = Tag::where('tagname', $query)->first();
$imageIds = $tag->images()->select('images.id')->get()->pluck('id')->toArray(); // assuming your images table name is "images" and primary key name is "id"
$images = Images::where(function($q) use($imageIds, $query) {
        $q->whereIn('id', $imageIds)
          ->orWhere('title', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%");
    })->whereIn('mature', [0, $mature])
      ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subHours($withinHours))
      ->orderBy($orderByString, 'desc')->paginate(50);
```

Comment: Updated my post. I'd like to point out that the images table and the tag table don't reference each other directly.  The images_tag table does, however. The columns are called tag_id and image_id. Your post is trying to get tag_id from the images table, not the pivot table.

Comment: My images table is indeed named "images" and its primary key is "id". However, I still get an error. I updated my post.